# How to track Ad Clicks in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, double-click-advertising

I would like to track ad click in Google Analytics with the purpose of calculating ROI per specific source of traffic.

So let's say we have 3 banners on the page (banners run through DFP), this page is being shared across multiple social networks where each share has different parameters in URL for tracking `(e.g. domain.com/utm_source=StumbleUpon&utm_campaign=post_share&utm_content=article_one`).

I want to see the report where I can see that Traffic Source #1 did N amount of clicks on banners.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify are you trying to track clicks on the DFP banners on your page or trying to see the clicks on the links that you've shared (e.g. domain.com/utm_source=StumbleUpon&utm_campaign=post_share&utm_content=article_one)

If you're on analytics 360 there is a DFP integration - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6183286?hl=en&ref_topic=6183302

Otherwise you could track clicks on the element containing the Ad units but  you wouldn't get revenue back from DFP into your Analytics reports

Comment: No, I am not running GA 360, I use free GA instead. It looks like you have to pay $150k per year to be able integrate DFP and GA.

I am sharing links with different parameters in URL, so I can track traffic from specific post from specific social network.

I need to track ad clicks on the banners on my site so I can track ROI.

So lets say I got 100 users from FB, 100 from Instagram, 100 from Twitter - I want to know which users brought me most revenue.